# How to express /abc/def in http://127.0.0.1/abc/def

Tags: word-usage

How to express `/abc/def`  in `http://127.0.0.1/abc/def` ?

`http://127.0.0.1/abc/def` is called url
`/abc/def` should called what??

BTW,I don't know which `tags` to choose
You can edit my `tags` , Thank you

Comment: This is a technical definition, answerable by Wikipedia ("path").  See [URI - Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)

Comment: @HostileFork: While that's certainly true, the policy on simple dictionary lookups does not extend to all possible reference sites on the Web — only dictionaries and thesauri, basically. "You can find this if you know how to look for it" matches an awful lot of questions.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Well, Wikipedia plus knowing URL seems to get one there pretty quickly... I think I'd put it on the list.  It isn't exactly what one would call "english"...

Comment: @HostileFork I agree with Nathan Tuggy here, event though I understand your point. To be fair for the OP, I believe that we should look at the question from the OP's point of view. Here is a quick challenge for a native speaker of English, what's `/abc/def` in `http://127.0.0.1/abc/def` called in Thai? (BTW, I think your comment and your link to the Wikipedia page would be a good answer. ;-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Likely `ชื่อเส้นทางไปยังไฟล์ที่`...but the thing is that I know the "name of that" involves specificity of "that" which seems beyond the scope here!

Comment: @HostileFork `ชื่อเส้นทางไปยังไฟล์ที่ = name of the route (or path) to the file which ...` -- That's pretty close! In real life, most everyone would simply call it "path", too, or transliterate it as พาธ in Thai.

Comment: @HostileFork - I'd call this English. I mean, the O.P. is looking for the English word (or technical term) for it. I don't know how this is "answerable by a dictionary." Where would you look in the dictionary for something like this? I think that closevote reason is more for questions like "What does _X_ mean?" where _X_ is some word easily found in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `http://127.0.0.1/abc/def` is called url

That is a URL, but more generally this category of thing is called a "URI"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-a-url-and-a-urn

> `/abc/def` should called what??

That portion is called the "path".  But take note that there can be portions after the path called the "query" and the "fragment".

Here is a [diagram from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) *(the article explains each part)*:

```
                    hierarchical part
        ┌───────────────────┴─────────────────────┐
                    authority               path
        ┌───────────────┴───────────────┐┌───┴────┐
  abc://username:password@example.com:123/path/data?key=value#fragid1
  └┬┘   └───────┬───────┘ └────┬────┘ └┬┘           └───┬───┘ └──┬──┘
scheme  user information     host     port            query   fragment

  urn:example:mammal:monotreme:echidna
  └┬┘ └──────────────┬───────────────┘
scheme              path
```

Interestingly (maybe), the "fragment" is [not sent to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/940923/211160) when you paste a URI into your address bar.  The browser sees it, but the server you are speaking to does not.